# Building SAC 101.6a

Tags: compiling

Has anyone tried to build Seismic Analysis Code?

```
http://ds.iris.edu/ds/nodes/dmc/software/downloads/sac/
```

I am trying to build SAC 101.6a, but getting

```
gcc         -I/home/hagbard/Opstk/src/sac/sac-101.6a/inc -I../libedit/include -D_GNU_SOURCE    -o sac main/sac.o -L/home/hagbard/Opstk/src/sac/sac-101.6a/src libsac_all.a libsgf.a libsac_x11.a libturtle.a libsac_all.a libevalresp.a libSMnonOracleFuncs.a  libSacOracleStubFuncs.a -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lX11  -lz     -lX11 ../libedit/lib/libedit.a -ldl -lm -lncurses 
libsac_all.a(xabout.o):(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `kmmsg'
main/sac.o:(.bss+0xbc60): first defined here
libsac_all.a(xabout.o):(.bss+0x7b8e0): multiple definition of `cmmsg'
main/sac.o:(.bss+0x87540): first defined here
libsac_all.a(erase.o):(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `kmgdm'
libsac_all.a(select.o):(.bss+0x20): first defined here
libsac_all.a(erase.o):(.bss+0xc40): multiple definition of `cmgdm'
libsac_all.a(select.o):(.bss+0xc60): first defined here
libsac_all.a(inigdm.o):(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `kmgdm'
libsac_all.a(select.o):(.bss+0x20): first defined here
libsac_all.a(inigdm.o):(.bss+0xc40): multiple definition of `cmgdm'
libsac_all.a(select.o):(.bss+0xc60): first defined here
...
libsac_all.a(inissi.o):(.bss+0xa0280): first defined here
libSMnonOracleFuncs.a(cssRead2_8FlatFiles.o):(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `dblJmpBuf'
libsac_all.a(inissi.o):(.bss+0xa0280): first defined here
libSMnonOracleFuncs.a(cssTableDump.o):(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `dblJmpBuf'
libsac_all.a(inissi.o):(.bss+0xa0280): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2965: recipe for target 'sac' failed
make[1]: *** [sac] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hagbard/Opstk/bld/sac/sac-101.6a/src'
Makefile:401: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that you will need to provide more context on what exactly you did that led up to this output. Did you run a configure script? What was the result? Die you assemble the `gcc` arguments yourself? If so, how?

Comment: sac-101.6a is an old version : 2013-11-21 ....... Bugs? https://ds.iris.edu/message-center/thread/2796/